[Blender4.0]How to make Curve.Bevel.Round not get squashed when moved

This is what I saw online

This is my

Probably you have non-uniform scaling.
Go to object mode and press Ctrl+A -> Scale

Alt-A just deselects the selected object. The correct hotkey is Ctrl-A > Scale.

Thank you! The problem was solved after Ctrl+A -> Scale

Oh thanks, @JohnEason, Fixed

No problem. I was looking to see if that was an alternative hotkey to use until I realised what it normally does! :))
